# Using webdeploy to set ACL on a folder only if that folder exists

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a project that has a folder on the server which contains uploaded files. I don't include it in the web deploy because it's massive!

So I have a wpp.targets file which skips deleting that folder and its contents (an important consideration :-))

However, I want to move away from manual server configuration so I'd like the web deploy to ensure that the IIS_USRS group has write permission on the UserMedia folder (so I never have to remember to check)

I found [this article](http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/SettingFolderPermissionsOnWebPublish.aspx) by [@sayed-ibrahim-hashimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105999/sayed-ibrahim-hashimi) which gets me almost all the way there. But MSDEPLOY throws an error while creating the WebDeploy package complaining that the folder is not present to set the ACL on - and it isn't present on my local machine...

So, my question is whether it is possible to amend [@sayed-ibrahim-hashimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105999/sayed-ibrahim-hashimi)'s method so that I can set an ACL only if a folder exists?

---

My wpp.targets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="SetupCustomAcls" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
        <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\UserMedia</Path>
        <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess>
        <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
        <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
      </MsDeploySourceManifest>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DeclareCustomParameters" AfterTargets="AddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="UserMediaSetAclParam">
        <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
        <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
        <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\UserMedia</Match>
        <Description>Add write permission to the UserMedia folder.</Description>
        <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/UserMedia</DefaultValue>
        <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/UserMedia</Value>
        <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
        <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
        <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
      </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>AddCustomSkipRules</OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseMsDeployExe>true</UseMsDeployExe>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AddCustomSkipRules">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipUserMediaFiles">
        <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>UserMedia$</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath></XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipUserMediaFolder">
        <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>UserMedia$</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath></XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipAppFiles">
        <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>apps$</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath></XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipAppFolder">
        <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>apps$</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath></XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```